# How to sql query in a for loop and store the query in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a sql database with one column of ID #'s and a another column that has the corresponding info of each ID. I have a vector that contains the ID #'s that I want the corresponding info to. How do I query only those specific ID's while also getting there corresponding information, and store it into a table?

I've tried for loops, I've tried filtering, and hard coding it.

```
                                                                con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data.db") 
                                                            df<-                                                                                                                        tbl(con,"kv") 
                                                                    newish         <- data.frame(df)
                                                            filter(person %in% IDs) %>% 
                                                                      collect()
```

After connecting call all the ID's in the vector given and extract the corresponding information and store it into a table

If I tired a for loop the table would not print all of the information, but rather only the information of the last ID in the vector, the filtering wouldn't work because it suggested that the vector only had to be of vector length one instead of 90,000. The actual results should be a table that contains only the patient ID #'s and the corresponding information of the people who I have in the vector.

Comment: The only code you've shared is the code that creates a db connection. Since that isn't the code you're having trouble with, maybe it would make sense to share the actual code that you've tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sql problem that you can decompose with R as follows :

```r
# not run
# con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "data.db") 

ids <- paste0("id_", sample(1:100, 10))
id_var <- "id_var" # you can put more ids here with a corresponding data.frame in ids
vars <- paste0("var", 1:10)
db_name <- "mydatabase"
tab_name <- "mytable"
whereq <- paste("where", id_var, "in", paste0("('", paste0(ids, collapse = "', '"), "')") )

rqt <- paste("select", paste(vars, collapse = ", "),
             "from", paste0(db_name, ".", tab_name), whereq, ";")
# check the query
rqt
#> [1] "select var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10 from mydatabase.mytable where id_var in ('id_99', 'id_1', 'id_72', 'id_86', 'id_65', 'id_59', 'id_67', 'id_4', 'id_82', 'id_2') ;"

# to uncomment
# res <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, rqt)
# res <- tibble::as_tibble(res) # OR data.table::data.table(res) OR as.data.frame(res)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>